# Scala String parser

Tags: xml, scala, apache-spark

I have a XML file in S3 contains the Schema for my table called sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<DATA  CHARSET="UTF8" DELIMITER="\t">
<COLUMNS>
<COLUMN DATA_PRECISION="10" DATA_SCALE="0" DATA_TYPE="NUMBER"  ID="APPLICATION_ID" />
<COLUMN DATA_LENGTH="40" DATA_TYPE="VARCHAR2" ID="DESCRIPTIVE_FLEXFIELD_NAME"/>
<COLUMN DATA_LENGTH="30" DATA_TYPE="VARCHAR2" ID="LANGUAGE"/>
<COLUMN DATA_PRECISION="15" DATA_SCALE="0" DATA_TYPE="NUMBER" ID="CREATED_BY" />
<COLUMN DATA_PRECISION="10" DATA_SCALE="0" DATA_TYPE="NUMBER" ID="LAST_UPDATE_LOGIN" />

</COLUMNS>
</DATA>
```

I already write script as `sample.filter( x => x.contains("DATA_TYPE") || x.contains("ID"))`, and I would need to get each pair of the value for (ID,DATA_TYPE) so the final output should be like

```
("APPLICATION_ID","NUMBER"),("DESCRIPTIVE_FLEXFIELD_NAME","VARCHAR2"),etc.
```

Anyone can help me on this?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use xml reader in spark as

```
val df = sqlContext.read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
  .option("rootTag", "DATA")
  .option("rowTag", "COLUMNS")
  .load("path to the xml file")
```

And apply some *inbuilt functions* such as `explode` and `select` as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.select(explode(col("COLUMN")))
  .select(col("col.*"))
  .filter(col("_DATA_TYPE").isNotNull || col("_ID").isNotNull)
  .select("_DATA_TYPE", "_ID")
```

which should give you

```
+----------+--------------------------+
|_DATA_TYPE|_ID                       |
+----------+--------------------------+
|NUMBER    |APPLICATION_ID            |
|VARCHAR2  |DESCRIPTIVE_FLEXFIELD_NAME|
|VARCHAR2  |LANGUAGE                  |
|NUMBER    |CREATED_BY                |
|NUMBER    |LAST_UPDATE_LOGIN         |
+----------+--------------------------+
```

Now you can convert it to rdd and parse as you want  or leave it as dataframe and apply other operations on it.

Answer (score 1):

While this can be done with `spark-xml` in an easier and more robust way. You can also use the `scala.xml` API to parse:

```
import scala.xml._

val rdd = sc.textFile("file.xml").filter( x => x.contains("DATA_TYPE") || x.contains("ID"))

rdd.map(XML.loadString(_) )
   .map(node => ( (node \\ "@ID").text , (node \\ "@DATA_TYPE").text  ) )
   .collect.foreach(println)

// (APPLICATION_ID,NUMBER)
// (DESCRIPTIVE_FLEXFIELD_NAME,VARCHAR2)
// (LANGUAGE,VARCHAR2)
// (CREATED_BY,NUMBER)
// (LAST_UPDATE_LOGIN,NUMBER)
```